# Eclipse maintains a lock on certain service's jars even when the service has been undeployed

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I run my tomcat from Eclipse, and use context files for deploying applications. But even when I have undeployed a service, and I try to build the service (i.e its snapshot) again using `mvn clean install`, it complains that some or the other jar is still being used somewhere, and it can't be deleted. The result is that I have to restart my Tomcat every time I need to do a build on any one of my individual service

Answer (score 0):

Use Tomcat installation, instead of deploying the web apps from the Eclipse Workspace. As in the picture:

[image]